# Closing older questions as duplicates of newer ones?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I've closed [How should I record sex change/gender reassignment?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/157/1006) as a duplicate of [Including name change for transgender person in genealogy](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/15847/1006) to put it on hold for discussion and editing.

Things I'd like feedback on:

1. Whether this specific should remain closed as a duplicate, or be open again as a related question.
2. Whether you are happy with editing that changes language usages like "living relative who was born male" to "living relative who was assigned male gender at birth" (in keeping with current guidelines from GLAAD and other organizations).
3. Suggestions for other changes that should be made so that the question is friendlier to our trans community members here at SE and potential members who would like to join us.
4. Is it ever a good idea to close the older question as a dupe of a new one, and if so, what would be your criteria for choosing which question to keep?

One of the reasons I was prompted to close the older question in favor of our new one is that the answer https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/14876/1006 brings up the privacy issues about living people which weren't really addressed in the other answers.  Copying and pasting my answer from https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/15849/1006 didn't seem appropriate.

Note that none of the answers on the older question were accepted.  However, I acknowledge that I have an obvious bias because the accepted answer on the newer question is mine.  I'm happy to see the older question open again, but I think it needs work.

One solution might be to edit for any problematic language, add a new answer with a reminder about the privacy answers which links to the newer question.  But I wanted community feedback before tearing into this older question.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 4. In general, according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/195988

> If the new question is a better question or has better answers, then vote to close the old one as a duplicate of the new one.

In this case, I think they're similar enough (and the later one is better) that this can be applied.

2. Am I happy with editing that changes language usages?

This is less clear cut -- amending language uses to conform with a specifically American usage doesn't quite sit right with me (even though I think it's well intended). Would the edit improve the clarity of the question?  I thunk I'd be happier to see a language usage suggestion included in an answer -- perhaps as a prompt on how to word things when recording the relevant events etc.

3. Other edits to make it friendlier to trans community members?

I can't think of any, but I'm not a member of the trans community. It is only a single-paragraph question, and I think concentrating effort on the newer question (if any is needed) would be time better spent.